# Can an unmarshalled type be a member of a marshalled type?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types, appdomain

Can I include a type that cannot be marshalled like System.Type in a class that inherits from MarshalByRefObject? Will this break the marshal-ability of the enclosing class?

Comment: What did you get when you tested it?

Comment: I have not tested it yet, I was wondering what the C# specs say about this kind of behavior. I know that for serialization, all members must also be serializable.

Comment: An MRBO object doesn't get marshaled in whole, each individual member is represented by the proxy.  You will not have a problem with a Type member, it is serializable.

Comment: @HansPassant Basically I was trying to load an assembly in another AppDomain and get all the types from the assembly and then unload the assembly. This requires that the assembly not get loaded into the main AppDomain because then it cannot be unloaded. When I try to get a variable of type System.Type (which tells me the metadata about the types in the assembly), it automatically loads the assembly into the main AppDomain. I understand that this question is not directly about the problem but it's part of the problem.